# How to check string is in json format

Tags: json, go

I want to create a function to receive an input string which can be string in json format or just a string. For example, something easy like following function.

```
func checkJson(input string){
   if ... input is in json ... {
      fmt.Println("it's json!")
   } else {
      fmt.Println("it's normal string!")
   }
}
```

Comment: Use the [json](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#example_Decoder) package and attempt to decode `[]byte(inputstring)` first? If you can give an example as to *why* you need to do this it might help us give you a better answer. It seems odd that you cannot determine when your application might be parsing JSON or not.

Comment: I want to wrap go http's sending request function. So, if parameter is json, I will set 'content-type' to 'application/jon', if not, I will set it to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Comment: If the string is `null` or `true` do you want to send it as JSON or not?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I was unclear if you needed to know about just a "quoted string" or if you needed to know about json, or the difference between both of them, so this shows you how to detect both scenarios so you can be very specific.

I posted the interactive code sample here as well: http://play.golang.org/p/VmT0BVBJZ7

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func isJSONString(s string) bool {
    var js string
    return json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &js) == nil

}

func isJSON(s string) bool {
    var js map[string]interface{}
    return json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &js) == nil

}

func main() {
    var tests = []string{
        `"Platypus"`,
        `Platypus`,
        `{"id":"1"}`,
    }

    for _, t := range tests {
        fmt.Printf("isJSONString(%s) = %v\n", t, isJSONString(t))
        fmt.Printf("isJSON(%s) = %v\n\n", t, isJSON(t))
    }

}
```

Which will output this:

```
isJSONString("Platypus") = true
isJSON("Platypus") = false

isJSONString(Platypus) = false
isJSON(Platypus) = false

isJSONString({"id":"1"}) = false
isJSON({"id":"1"}) = true
```

Comment: Your `isJSON` function should have `var js interface{}` for maximum generality

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood I agree if you are just doing straight json, for this example,I was unclear as to if he needed to know the difference between a quoted string, or valid json.  Using interface would accept either and for this example I didn't want that.

Comment: @CoryLaNou ...but a quoted string *is* valid JSON!

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood I understand and agree, but was unclear as to his needs.  What if he just wants to know if it is SIMPLY a string, which while valid, he doesn't want it to match a structure like {"id":"1"}.  If he doesn't care, then yes, use interface, if he does care, then use map[string]interface to differentiate.  Without the use case, I was only guessing but wanted to show the differences.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for nice answer. I've just known that a quoted string is also a valid JSON. I thought JSON is always key-pair. But your answer really covers all of my use cases as I want to wrap go http's sending request function. So, if parameter is json, I will set 'content-type' to 'application/json', if not, I will set it to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Comment: Hi again, I wonder a quoted string is really a valid JSON? I was trying a quoted string on jsonlint.com and it always tell me to add '{' or '['

Comment: @A-letubby: "A string is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes. A character is represented as a single character string." [JSON](http://json.org/)

Comment: @peterSO I read your link and it says "JSON is built on two structures:

A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed list, or associative array.
An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence."

So, basically a quoted string is not JSON. NickCraig-Wood and CoryLaNou might be wrong?

Comment: What about `[{"id":"1"}]`? This is valid JSON, too, but your scripts say it is not.

Comment: @NickCraig-Wood thanks, only after replacing ```map[string]interface{}```with just ```ìnterface{}``` I was able to validate a randomly generated, large but valid JSON file.

Comment: You should use `var js json.RawMessage` instead, because this way the message will not be unmarshalled, hence it will be faster and there will be less mem allocations.

Comment: interestingly, profiling with `var js interface{}` vs. `var js json.RawMessage`. `var js json.RawMessage` is > 2x as fast because it avoids any reflection.

Comment: this doesn't work with json arrays. please accept @william-king answer.

Comment: `null` is also valid JSON.

Answer (score 80):

For anyone else looking for a way to validate any JSON string regardless of schema, try the following:

```
func IsJSON(str string) bool {
    var js json.RawMessage
    return json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &js) == nil
}
```

Comment: This should be the top answer, people. The current accepted answer fails for JSON arrays `[{"key": "value1"}, {"key": "value2"}]`. Also, an alternative way to do it: https://play.golang.org/p/0IfY696ubM

Comment: This should be the excepted answer, not only does the current excepted answer fail on arrays, it uses reflection to do the marshaling and all that is asked for is a check, causing the excepted answer to take over twice as long!

Comment: i don't know why, but if you pass `"somestring"` (with double quotes) into that function, it returns true

Comment: @srf That's because JSON allows for raw strings and numbers to be serialized, theres no requirement for JSON to be included in a set of brackets or braces. JSON strings require double quotes to surround them to be valid.

This function will also return true with plain ints / floats as those are also valid JSON. See here for an example: https://play.golang.org/p/ev8kByJvx2Y

Answer (score 28):

Standard `encoding/json` library contains [json.Valid](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Valid) function starting from go 1.9 - see https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18086 . This function may be used for checking whether the provided string is a valid json:

```
if json.Valid(input) {
    // input contains valid json
}
```

But `json.Valid` may be quite slow comparing to third-party solutions such as [fastjson.Validate](https://godoc.org/github.com/valyala/fastjson#Validate), which is up to 5x faster than the standard `json.Valid` - see `json validation` section in [benchmarks](https://github.com/valyala/fastjson#benchmarks).

Answer (score 6):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func isJSONString(s string) bool {
    var js string
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &js)
    return err == nil
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(isJSONString(`"Platypus"`))
    fmt.Println(isJSONString(`Platypus`))
}
```

Output:

```
true
false
```

Comment: What about `[{"id":"1"}]`? This is valid JSON, too, but your scripts say it is not.

Comment: As pointed out by Martin, this fails for, `[{"key": "value1"}, {"key": "value2"}]`. Most people aren't looking to validate things like `"Platypus"`. They want to validate large JSON arrays.

Comment: What about `null`? This is valid JSON, too, but your script says it isn't.

Answer (score 5):

This might be an older post to the actual function in the standard library.

But you can just use the json.Valid() function in the "encoding/json" package.

```
   var tests = []string{
    `"Platypus"`,
    `Platypus`,
    `{"id":"1"}`,
    `{"id":"1}`,
}

for _, t := range tests {
    fmt.Printf("is valid: (%s) = %v\n", t, json.Valid([]byte(t)))
    
}
```

example https://play.golang.org/p/nfvOzQB919s

Answer (score 2):

In searching for an answer to this question, I found https://github.com/asaskevich/govalidator, which was tied to this blog post which describes creating an input validator: https://husobee.github.io/golang/validation/2016/01/08/input-validation.html. Just in case someone is looking for a quick library on doing this, I thought it would be useful to put that tool in an easy-to-find place.

This package uses the same method for isJSON that William King suggests, as follows:

```
// IsJSON check if the string is valid JSON (note: uses json.Unmarshal).
func IsJSON(str string) bool {
    var js json.RawMessage
    return json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &js) == nil
}
```

This package gave me some greater insight into JSON in go, so it seemed useful to put here.

Answer (score 1):

The current accepted answer (as of July 2017) fails for JSON arrays and hasn't been updated: https://repl.it/J8H0/10

Try this:

```
func isJSON(s string) bool {
  var js interface{}
  return json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &js) == nil
}
```

Or William King's solution, which is better.

Answer (score 0):

how about you use something like this:

```
if err := json.Unmarshal(input, temp_object); err != nil {
    fmt.Println("it's normal string!")
} else {
    fmt.Println("it's json!")
}
```