# Check JSON string valid or not in golang

Tags: json, go, marshalling, unmarshalling

I want to check whether an interface that comes from my application is valid json or not. I have searched. It could be duplicate of here: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22128282/how-to-check-string-is-in-json-format) (but it did not work) I found some methods.  One of them is Marshaling then Unmarshaling the interface like the following code:

```
func isJSONClasic(i interface{}) bool {
    x, err := json.Marshal(i)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %+v\n", err)
    }
    var temp interface{}
    return json.Unmarshal(x, &temp) == nil
}
```

Another method I used is gjson package. According to its documentation in [here](https://godoc.org/github.com/tidwall/gjson#ValidBytes), it has **ValidBytes** method. It takes a byte arrray and returns the validation. The function I used is like following:

```
func isJSONGjson(i interface{}) bool {
    x, err := json.Marshal(i)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %+v\n", err)
    }
    return gjson.ValidBytes(x)
}
```

The sample data I used is **{"name""latif"}**. It is easy to see that it is not a valid json. (Also I tested in [here](https://jsonlint.com/))
When I test the data with the 2 functions, I expected that they should print false as the result of the validation, but I get true for both of them.
The whole code I tested and result is like following:
package main

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/tidwall/gjson"
)

func main() {
    var data interface{}
    data = `{"name""latif"}`

    isValid := isJSONClasic(data)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", isValid)

    isValid = isJSONGjson(data)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", isValid)
}

func isJSONClasic(i interface{}) bool {
    x, err := json.Marshal(i)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %+v\n", err)
    }
    var temp interface{}
    return json.Unmarshal(x, &temp) == nil
}

func isJSONGjson(i interface{}) bool {
    x, err := json.Marshal(i)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %+v\n", err)
    }
    return gjson.ValidBytes(x)
}
```

The output is following:

[image]

Even the sample data is not valid, I get true. What is wrong in here? How can I learn a json is valid or not with golang?

Comment: Just unmarshal the input string, and see if there are any errors.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I did your suggestion in isJSONClasic function. To obtain Unmarshal function paremeters, I used marshal function.

Comment: The current problem is that you're marshaling your JSON string even though it is already a string. So you're **always** generating a valid JSON string, which is basically encoded one time too much. Don't call marshal on your JSON string. [Example here](https://play.golang.org/p/18zq2h6h9eE). You can use [`json.Valid`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json?tab=doc#Valid) instead, e.g. `json.Valid([]byte(data))`

Comment: No, do not marshal. You should only unmarshal the string: `json.Unmarshal([]byte(str),&v)` and check the error

Comment: @BurakSerdar yes it worked. but an interface{} comes from my application. So data.([]byte) can not works every time. some times I get map[string]interface{}, sometimes just string. So how can I use the come interface as byte array in unmarshall function?

Comment: @xarantolus thank you for the example

Comment: Use a type assertion to check if it is a string. If it is map[string]interface{}, then this function is meaningless.

Comment: @BurakSerdar thank you for your suggestions. I can do it by using switch case, but I wanted to convert my interface to byte array generically. I learned that I can do it with encoding/gob package. Again thank you for your suggestions and interest

Comment: That is wrong. You can't convert an interface to []byte. You can encode data using different encodings, and what you're doing here is mixing gob encoding with json. What is the point of unmarshaling the output of  gob?

Comment: You are right. to use the word 'convert' was wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here an example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/gob"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var data interface{}
    data = `{"name""latif"}`
    valid := `{"name":"latif"}`

    isValid := isValidJSON(data)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", isValid)
    isValid = isValidJSON(valid)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", isValid)
}

func isValidJSON(i interface{}) bool {
    var str map[string]string
    data, err := getBytes(i)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    data = data[4:]
    err = json.Unmarshal(data, &str)
    return err == nil
}

func getBytes(i interface{}) ([]byte, error) {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    enc := gob.NewEncoder(&buf)
    err := enc.Encode(i)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return buf.Bytes(), nil
}
```

Note: The first 4 byte after the encoding of the `interface` to `[]byte` have to be removed

---

Result:

```
false
true
```

Comment: This is wrong. Gob encoding is different from json encoding, and feeding the output of gob to json unmarshal has no practical meaning.

Comment: I have used the gob only for convert interface to byte array ....

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("isJSON: ", isJSON("abc"))
    fmt.Println("isJSON: ", isJSON("{}"))
    fmt.Println("isJSON: ", isJSON("{a:22}"))
    fmt.Println("isJSON: ", isJSON("[]"))
    fmt.Println("isJSON: ", isJSON("[222,2223]"))
}

func isJSON(str string) bool {
    fmt.Println("check", str)
    var data map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &data)
    if err == nil {
        return true
    } else {
        //fmt.Println("check json format not object:", err)
    }

    var data2 []any
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &data2)
    if err == nil {
        return true
    } else {
        //fmt.Println("check json format not array:", err)
    }
    return false
}
```

```js
check abc
isJSON:  false

check {}
isJSON:  true

check {a:22}
isJSON:  false

check []
isJSON:  true

check [222,2223]
isJSON:  true
```